# How to remove space between divs in different lines

Tags: css, reactjs

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cirossmonteiro/n5u2wwjg/215931/).
I'd like to know how to remove the space between lines. I've already tried removing <br />, but nothing changes. Also I don't want to put negative values for margin-bottom. I don't know whether it's a react or css matter.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

**React**

```
class Square extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.style = {
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
            borderStyle: 'solid',
            borderWidth: 1
        }
    }
    render () {
        return (<div class = "square" style = {this.style}></div>);
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.m; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.props.n; j++) {
            ret.push(<Square></Square>);
        }
        ret.push(<br />);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App m = "10" n = "10" />,document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: add vertical-align:top

Comment: It worked, but I've changed the height and width from 20px to 15px and the issue came back. [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)

Comment: because the default font-size is 16px and now you made the element less with 15px ... use font-size:0 or line-height:0

Comment: Still not working: https://jsfiddle.net/cirossmonteiro/n5u2wwjg/218430/

Comment: font-size and line-height on the container, not the elements

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that class is reserved for creating components in react. So to add css class names to jsx elements you should use className prop instead of class

Change

```
 render () {
    return (<div class = "square" style = {this.style}></div>);
}
```

To

```
 render () {
    return (<div className= "square" style = {this.style}></div>);
}
```

And change your css to

```
 div.square {
     display:inline-block; 
     margin:0;
     vertical-align:top;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
  }
```